# Laravel:Dont show error if relation dont exist

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have controller and i am getting data like this

> $events= Eventm::with('teacher')->get();

Every event has one teacher then in view i am taking data like

```
$event['teacher']->name
```

its work fine if their their is relation between teacher and events. but if their is no teacher in teacher column (or Admin delete the teacher but still event contain the teacher id). the view don't render at all and show error trying to get property of non object. I want that if teacher data is deleted the view will not throw error , just show no text on

```
$event['teacher']->name
```

is it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do in your view

```
@if($event['teacher'])
   <div class="whatever">$event['teacher']->name</div>
@else
   <div class="whatever">Teacher not found.</div>
@endif
```

Another possibility is to do what you should be doing anyway: pass from controller the data to be displayed in the view. Your view should not be complicated and it should not be aware of your objects and your data, you should pass to it the data it is supposed to display. This is somethig you should be doing in a presenter or just in another class:

```
<?php

class ProcessEventsViewData {

    private $events;

    public function __construct($events) 
    {
        $this->processData($events);
    }

    public function processData($data) 
    {
        foreach($data as $event)
        {
            $this->processEvent($event);
        }
    }

    public function processEvent($event) 
    {
        $this->events[$event->id]['name'] = $event->name ?: 'Event name not found';
        $this->events[$event->id]['teacher'] = $event->teacher ? $event->teacher->toArray() : array('name', 'Teacher not found');
    }

    public function getData() 
    {
        return $this->events;
    }

}

class MyController extends Controller {

    $events = Eventm::with('teacher')->get();

    $eventData = new ProcessEventsViewData($events);

    return View::make('event')->with('events', $eventData->getData());
}
```

And in your view you now can just:

```
@foreach($events as $id => $event)
   Event ID: {{$id}};
   Event Name: {{$event['name']}};
   Teacher: {{$event['teacher']['name']}};
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thanks for your time .Yes , but  is there any  other way. i mean if i have  20 variables in one view. this way will make view more complicated.